# How I can maximize the Get query length?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm using Godaddy hosting plan & I create a php page to submit information to my lead buyer using get method. ode is working fine & when I click on submit data, it runs the query but didn't take the complete data with it. S I need to know how I can increase the query length so it takes my complete data with it. Here are few points that might help you understanding my problem.

1. I tried Chrome, Firefox. Results are same on both browser.
2. I can't use post method, because it's allowed to do so, So I need to post it using GET method in any way.
3. I'm attaching the PHP code so you can get the idea what i'm doing exactly.

   ```
   echo "<td><a href=https://example.com/api.php?Key=wlbZRZ8KuFn7t.npuFsftlCKwBNpIpKrtFYZR0I7tfOfu0OHIE8BtFPrvAbi&API_Action=pingPostLead&Test_Lead=1&Mode=full&TYPE=71&IP_Address=000.000.0.0&SRC=directsw_autinsd&Landing_Page=replace_this&Driver_1_Ownership=Owned&Driver_1_Primary_Use=CommuteWork&Driver_1_Annual_Mileage=12000&Driver_1_Vehicle_Parking=Unknown&Driver_1_Salvaged_Vehicle=No&Age=Unknown&Driver_1_License_Status=Unknown&Driver_1_Filing_Required=None&Driver_1_Education=High%20School&Driver_1_Occupation=Not%20Listed&Driver_1_Age_When_First_Licensed=Unknown&Driver_1_FullTime_Student=No&Driver_1_Tickets_Accidents_Claims_Past_3_Years=Unknown&Driver_1_Bankruptcy_In_Past_5_Years=No&Driver_1_Additional_Drivers=No&Driver_1_Additional_Vehicles=No&Driver_1_DUI_DWI_In_The_Past_5_Years=No&Driver_1_Reposessions_In_The_Past_5_Years=Unknown&Driver_1_Desired_Collision_Coverage=No%20Coverage&Driver_1_Desired_Comprehensive_Coverage=No%20Coverage&Driver_1_First_Name=" . $row["firstname"] . "&Driver_1_Last_Name= " . $row["lastname"] . "&Driver_1_Address=" . $row["address"] . "&Driver_1_City=" . $row["city"] . "&Driver_1_State=" . $row["state"] . "&Driver_1_Zip=" . $row["zip"] . "&Driver_1_Daytime_Phone=" . $row["phone"] . "&Driver_1_Email=" . $row["email"] . "&Driver_1_Year_Of_Vehicle=" . $row["vyear"] . "&Driver_1_Make_Of_Vehicle=" . $row["vmake"] . "&Driver_1_Model_Of_Vehicle=" . $row["vmodel"] . "&Driver_1_Birthdate=" . $row["birthdate"] . "&Driver_1_Gender=" . $row["gender"] . "&Driver_1_Marital_Status=" . $row["mstatus"] . "&Driver_1_Credit_Rating=" . $row["creditrating"] . "&Driver_1_Current_Residence=" . $row["residence"] . "&Driver_1_Licensed_State=" . $row["lstate"] . "&Driver_1_Insured_Past_30_Days=" . $row["past30days"] . ">Submit</a></td>";
   ```

Comment: You *really should* use POST for this. End of story.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're missing quotes around your `href`. Try this. Note that you really, really, *really*, should use `POST` for this.

```
echo "<td><a href=\"https://example.com/api.php?Key=wlbZRZ8KuFn7t.npuFsftlCKwBNpIpKrtFYZR0I7tfOfu0OHIE8BtFPrvAbi&API_Action=pingPostLead&Test_Lead=1&Mode=full&TYPE=71&IP_Address=000.000.0.0&SRC=directsw_autinsd&Landing_Page=replace_this&Driver_1_Ownership=Owned&Driver_1_Primary_Use=CommuteWork&Driver_1_Annual_Mileage=12000&Driver_1_Vehicle_Parking=Unknown&Driver_1_Salvaged_Vehicle=No&Age=Unknown&Driver_1_License_Status=Unknown&Driver_1_Filing_Required=None&Driver_1_Education=High%20School&Driver_1_Occupation=Not%20Listed&Driver_1_Age_When_First_Licensed=Unknown&Driver_1_FullTime_Student=No&Driver_1_Tickets_Accidents_Claims_Past_3_Years=Unknown&Driver_1_Bankruptcy_In_Past_5_Years=No&Driver_1_Additional_Drivers=No&Driver_1_Additional_Vehicles=No&Driver_1_DUI_DWI_In_The_Past_5_Years=No&Driver_1_Reposessions_In_The_Past_5_Years=Unknown&Driver_1_Desired_Collision_Coverage=No%20Coverage&Driver_1_Desired_Comprehensive_Coverage=No%20Coverage&Driver_1_First_Name=" . $row["firstname"] . "&Driver_1_Last_Name= " . $row["lastname"] . "&Driver_1_Address=" . $row["address"] . "&Driver_1_City=" . $row["city"] . "&Driver_1_State=" . $row["state"] . "&Driver_1_Zip=" . $row["zip"] . "&Driver_1_Daytime_Phone=" . $row["phone"] . "&Driver_1_Email=" . $row["email"] . "&Driver_1_Year_Of_Vehicle=" . $row["vyear"] . "&Driver_1_Make_Of_Vehicle=" . $row["vmake"] . "&Driver_1_Model_Of_Vehicle=" . $row["vmodel"] . "&Driver_1_Birthdate=" . $row["birthdate"] . "&Driver_1_Gender=" . $row["gender"] . "&Driver_1_Marital_Status=" . $row["mstatus"] . "&Driver_1_Credit_Rating=" . $row["creditrating"] . "&Driver_1_Current_Residence=" . $row["residence"] . "&Driver_1_Licensed_State=" . $row["lstate"] . "&Driver_1_Insured_Past_30_Days=" . $row["past30days"] . "\">Submit</a></td>";
```

Comment: @jboneca I already know that I should use post method for this. but the problem is my buyer is only accepting data using GEt method. It's actually PingPost system if you are familiar with it. I'm really thank full if you can give me a few hints how I can use post instead of GET.